# Ошибка при установке Cupy на Python

Tags: python

После переустановки Windows 10, Microsoft Visual C++ и CUDA 11.6 устанавливаю библиотеки Python 3.10. Для установки Cupy использую команды: `pip install cupy-cuda116`, `pip install cupy` и `pip install cupy-10.5.0+cuda116-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl`. Появляется ошибка:

```
Collecting cupy-cuda116
Using cached cupy_cuda116-10.6.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (62.4 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.25,>=1.18 in c:\python310\lib\site-packages (from cupy-cuda116) (1.22.4+mkl)
Collecting fastrlock>=0.5
  Using cached fastrlock-0.8.tar.gz (68 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for fastrlock, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: fastrlock, cupy-cuda116
  Running setup.py install for fastrlock ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for fastrlock did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [16 lines of output]
      building without Cython
      running install
      C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\fastrlock
      copying fastrlock\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\fastrlock
      copying fastrlock\rlock.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\fastrlock
      copying fastrlock\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\fastrlock
      copying fastrlock\_lock.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\fastrlock
      running build_ext
      building 'fastrlock.rlock' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> fastrlock

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: Ну написано "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required.", значит С++ либо не установлен, либо не той версии. Может 64-битный нужен.

Comment: Решил проблему. В Visual Studio Installer поставил галочку 'Разработка классических приложений', установилось 10 Гб. После этого успешно установил Cupy.

Comment: Можете добавить как ответ к своему вопросу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При установке 'Visual Studio' или в 'Visual Studio Installer' поставить галочку 'Разработка классических приложений', установится примерно 10 Гб. Установить CUDA, которую можно скачать на сайте Nvidia. После этого в командной строке установить 'Cupy' с помощью команды `pip install cupy-cuda116` (где '116' - это версия CUDA 11.6). В Python проверить, что Cupy установилась с помощью `import cupy`